# Dagster-image cli

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, dagster

recreate the image deployment describe here:
https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/tree/master/python_modules/automation/automation/docker/images
How do I install the dagster-image  cli?
`dagster-image build-all --name <YOUR IMAGE>`
I tried running pip install -e . from setup.py folder https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/blob/master/python_modules/automation/setup.py
to install the command dagster-image , but i get an error below:
`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/sbin/dagster-image'`

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you want to build your own custom Docker image of user code deployment in Dagster. Here is a simple workaround:

Build your image on top of the official Dagster [user-code-example](https://hub.docker.com/r/dagster/user-code-example).

```
FROM dagster/user-code-example:latest

RUN pip install \
    ...your dependencies

COPY your_repo/ /
```